# Presto Admin installion Error

Tags: presto

I am getting the below error while trying to install the presto amdin 1.5.1

> ERROR Paramiko could not be imported. This usually means that pycrypto (a 
>   dependency of paramiko) has been compiled against a different libc version. > Ensure the presto-admin installer is built on the same OS as the target 
>   installation OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offline installer (which you are using) is compiled for libc version 2.12 (e.g. it works for Centos 6 and some other OSes, but not for Ubuntu 12.04+). Use the online installer for other OSes: https://github.com/prestodb/presto-admin/releases/download/1.5.1/prestoadmin-1.5.1-online.tar.bz2.